# Frame smoothing code

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

Ok, this is probably something very basic I don't understand about actionscript, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this.

I have some code that's supposed to smooth out the animation on an ENTER_FRAME loop:

```
private var m_lastTime:Number;
private var clock_speed:Number = 5;
    private function frameLoop(evt:Event):void 
    {
        var currTime:int = getTimer();
        var deltaTime:Number = ( currTime - this.m_lastTime ) * 0.001;
        this.m_lastTime = currTime;
        //trace(deltaTime.toString() + "," + (deltaTime * clock_speed).toString());

        // why you no work?
        var n:Number = clock_speed * deltaTime;
        trace(n);
        mcClockHand.rotation += .18;//  Number(deltaTime * clock_speed);
```

So as you can see, I'm calculating the time delta between frames, and multiplying it by a speed constant. I come up with a Number value and trace it to the output widow. It fluctuates between 0.14 and 0.19, averaging 0.18.

If I use that value to offset the rotation of a clockhand MC, it NEVER MOVES.
If I use the constant 0.18 as shown above, it moves right along at roughly 1 rotation per 30 seconds.

So they're both Number type, and the trace shows me that they're roughly the same value. Why is one able to move the MC and the other isn't?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It sounds like you are getting some int conversion error. Could you try changing `private var clock_speed:Number = 5;` to `private var clock_speed:Number = 5.0;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first loop, the first calculation of `deltaTime` results in `NaN` because `this.m_lastTime` is null. From there, your code is trying to increment an Object that is not a number. A simple solution would be to set the  `m_lastTime` variable to `0` when you declare it:

```
private var m_lastTime:Number = 0;
```

The better solution would be to check for a case when your calculation results in NaN.

```
var n:Number = clock_speed * deltaTime;
if (isNaN(n)) n = 0;
trace(n);
mcClockHand.rotation += n;//  Number(deltaTime * clock_speed);
```

Comment: ah, ok. so you're saying the first time through the loop, m_lastTime is null, which makes deltaTime NaN, and then when I add that to rotation, IT becomes NaN? So the next time through the loop, even though m_lastTime is now a real number, and therefore deltaTime is now a real number, rotation will always be NaN since NaN + 5 == NaN? Is that right?

Comment: Pretty much. NaN can be tricky because it IS a valid value of a Number and won't throw an error. But, it can still cause unexpected behavior in an application.

Answer (score 1):

you have no initial value for `m_lastTime` when you first use it. If you initialize the var when you declare it, `var m_lastTime:Number = getTimer();` it works.